# Syntax error in a Fortran FORMAT statement

Tags: fortran, string-formatting, gfortran

[image: screenshot of the terminal showing error] I am using the gfortran compiler and I am unable to find the syntax error in the line. Can anyone tell me the syntax error in the given line?

```
7 FORMAT(1X, 'a=',F8.8, 1X,'b=',F8.8, 2X, 'REAL=',F8.5, 2X, 'IMAG=',F8.5, 2X, 'k1=',F8.8, 2X, 'LDF=',F8.8)
```

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please also supply the exact error message.

Comment: What is your file extension on your Fortran program? If it is .f or .f77 this would be Fixed Form Fortran and statements can only go in columns 7 through 72. This line would go beyond that. As others have said, please give us more if you want help.

Comment: In addition to previous comments, some more code could be useful...

Comment: Usually the compiler shows where the issue is. A close paraend is usually required after an open paraend.

Comment: Yes, my guess is that it's fixed format and this line is much too long. But without more info it is purely a guess

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The error was marked as syntax error that too below 1X. The extension of the file is .f

Comment: There are two 1x's in the Format statement as given. Plese edit the question to include the error message as reported by the compiler (i.e. cut and paste it), and also the information that it is a .f file. Further the exact command you used to compile the code would be useful. Best of all would be a complete, short program that illustrates the problem, as requested above by albert.

Comment: It is very hard to tell but it looks like that the `7` is at position 7. Are there any tab characters in the source file (shouldn't be!). See to it that the `7` is in the columns 1-5. See to it that Format starts at position 7 or later. Split the format string before position 72 (don't forget the continuation character in column 6). But upmost importance show a small complete subroutine / program showing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem stems from the fact that the format statement is too long. I just ran a short f77 file and I put a format statement in the file that was longer than 72 spaces. This generated an error message and said the format statement was too long. I suggest you split that line with 2nd half being on the next line. When you do that put a character in column 6 to indicate to compiler that its a continuation line. Now your format statement should look like this:

```
7  FORMAT(1X, 'a=',F8.8, 1X,'b=',F8.8, 2X, 'REAL=',F8.5, 2X, 
  >      'IMAG=',F8.5, 2X, 'k1=',F8.8, 2X, 'LDF=',F8.8)
```

Notice the '>' character must be in column 6..

If your editor doesn't indicate column number then type a line in your code that looks like this:

C123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

you can use this to determine columns. Also notice that the C must be in column 1 because that indicates that the line is a comment and the compiler won't try to compile it.

Comment: Thanks, @jmh and all for the inputs! Yes, the error was because of the format statement which was too long. Now my program is working fine!